Scroll to bottom works fine but scroll to top doesn't on Google Chrome
I've made two JS functions. One that scrolls to top on click and the other that scrolls to bottom. The one that scrolls to bottom works 100% of the time. However, the scroll to top sometimes stops for no reason. It basically just scrolls a couple of pixels and then stops, then if I press the button again it will scroll to top. I'm only seeing this weird behaviour in Chrome and not in Firefox.
Functions:
function scrollToBottom() {
  const scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
  const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
  const scrollTo = scrollHeight - viewportHeight;
  
  window.scrollTo({
      top: scrollTo,
      behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}

function scrollToTop() {
  // I've tried with the window.scrollTo({top:0}) approach but it's the same result
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}

I should note, this only happens when smooth scrolling is enabled in Chrome. Has anybody had a similar issue and how did you fix it?
